# Temporary file not deletable?

Tags: python, file-permissions, delete-file

I have create the temporary file using the `tempfile.mkstemp()` and after creating this, I have get the unique path of the file inside the `path` and now I want to delete the temporary file. My code is given below.

I have already visit this [WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'new.dat'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322932/windowserror-error-32-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being)
 but did not solve my problem.

**Code**

```
import os
import tempfile

path=tempfile.mkstemp('.png', 'bingo',
    'C:\\Users\\MuhammadUsman\\Documents\\PythonScripts\\Project')
os.unlink(path)
```

**Error**

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
because it is being used by another process:
'C:\\Users\\MuhammadUsman\\Documents\\PythonScripts\\Project\\bingois3q1b3u.png'
```

Comment: tell me the reason of why down voted. Read the question carefully. I have tried many possible combinations .Don't down voted without reading the questions.

Comment: Temporary files usually delete themselves automatically if created via the `tempfile` module, so you probably don't need to be trying to do it manually.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible that your problem is that you're trying to access a file in the user directory for "MuhammadUsman"?  Did you perhaps copy and paste that from another post on SO without updating the path with your user name?

Comment: > Temporary files usually delete themselves automatically...

[I'm afraid not.](https://superuser.com/a/318514/451162)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: this works for me.

```
import os
import tempfile

fd,path=tempfile.mkstemp('.png', 'bingo', 'C:\\Users\\MuhammadUsman\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Project')
os.close(fd)
os.unlink(path)
```

Comment: Explanation: Python's use of the pseudo-POSIX `_open` function happens cause issues due to Windows being a bit inconsistent on use of `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` mode. [Some related info on CPython bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue14243). Basically, the sharing mode used by `mkstemp` and `unlink` disagrees, so the file can't be opened for delete until the handle from `mkstemp` is closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to get the unique name then try this. This is better than the upper solution. There is no need to delete the file. File automatically will be deleted.

```
import os
import tempfile

path=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='C:\\Users\\MuhammadUsman\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Project',suffix='.png').name
```